# How to pass value in ArrayList from method to method

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

```
public Program()
    {
        amount_bike = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void push(int value)
    {
        this.amount_bike.Add(value);
    }

    public int amount_bike_pop()
    {
        if (this.amount_bike.Count == 0)
        {
            return -100000;
        }
        int lastItem = (int)this.amount_bike[this.amount_bike.Count - 1];
        this.amount_bike.RemoveAt(this.amount_bike.Count - 1);
        return lastItem;
    }

    public static void Bike_status()
    {
        bool exit = false;

        Program available = new Program();
        available.push(0);
        available.push(0);
        available.push(50);
        WriteLine("E-bike available for rent is : " + available.amount_bike_pop() + " bikes.");
        WriteLine("Rented E-bike is : " + available.amount_bike_pop() + " bikes.");
        WriteLine("Broke E-bike is : " + available.amount_bike_pop() + " bikes.");

        WriteLine("\n");
        WriteLine("Please enter a number: 1 is back to pervoius menu or 0 to Exit");
        int input = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

        while (exit == false)
        {
            if (input == 1)
            {
                Clear();
                exit = true;
                continue;
            }
            else if (input == 0)
            {
                Clear();
                Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                Clear();
                Bike_status();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void Add_bike()
    {
        
    }
```

I study data structures and Algorithms. In this code, I keep the value in an ArrayList named "available" in the Bike_status method. I need to pass a value in an ArrayList to the Add_bike method. How do I pass a value from one method to another? Actually, I need to pass valus such as 50 to plus some number that I push in Console.ReadLine.

Comment: Note that `ArrayList` is about 16 years out of date.  See the **[note in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8)**.

Comment: You have a push method which has an integer value as parameter. You need to use the similar approach to create new method and call it by passing value to it..

Comment: what `Add_bike` method is supposed to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to slow down.at starting point of programming sometimes it's confusing.

> How do I pass a value from one method to another?

The simple answer is easy ,you want something to use in the function then in your method(s) you create parameter and pass the things you want to it.
like

//edit method to get int value ->  public static void Bike_status()

```
  public static void Bike_status(int value)
```

//edit when to call

```
  else
  {
        Clear();
        Bike_status(input);//send int value in 
  }
```

But really, what is that do you really want to learn?
if it OOP? I recommend you study this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/

To put it simply you has bicycle shop class separate from main program then use the method in that class
e.g.

//bicycle class

```
 public class Bicycles{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    pulibc string status {get;set; }
    public Bicycles(int p_id, string p_status)
    {
         ID = p_id;
         status=p_status; 
    }
 }
```

//bicycle shop class

```
 public class BicyclesShop{
     public List<Bicycle> available {get;set;} // class member  
     public BicyclesShop() // go search keyword  "constructor"
     {  
           available  = new List<Bicycle> (); 
     }
     //other method

     public void Add_bike()
     {
          // I can access  available object ! 
          // do anything with this class member(s) !
     }
     public void Bike_status(int inputVal)
     {
         // do something with inputVal , change some properties? 
     }

     //other methods
      public int amount_bike_pop()
      { 
           return available.Count();
      }
      public int amount_bike_broken_pop()
      {
          return available.Where(o=>o.status  =="Broken").Count(); // go search linq
      }
 }
```

//To use in Main program method

```
    BicyclesShop bs =new BicyclesShop();
    bs.available.Add( new Bicycle(1 ,"OK") ); //add bicycle #1 in list
    bs.available.Add( new Bicycle(2),"Broken" ); //add bicycle #2 in list

    WriteLine("Broke E-bike is : " + bs.amount_bike_broken_pop() + " bikes.");
```